# Howto notify NPM of dependency on native C++ library?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-gyp

Say I have a dynamic C++ library 'MyLib', including public headers, that will install to the platform specific default folders/paths.
I also have a NPM package that builds a native node extension 'MyLib.node', using node-gyp, that wraps the functionality of 'MyLib'.

Is there maybe a way to gracefully notify NPM that this package is dependent on the 'MyLib' library, using package.json, instead of letting it fail miserably during build? Or do I have to go via another route, like making it a full-blown platform specific install package (which I hope not, because I like cross-platforminess so much)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: no, NPM itself doesn't have such a feature.

There are various methods to deal with native library requirements:

- Use something like [`node-pre-gyp`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-pre-gyp) to download precompiled binaries, with fallback to compilation if there is no binary available for the platform in question. This method is used by, for instance, [`sqlite3`](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3) and [`canvas`](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas).
- Ship with the C/C++ code as part of the package, and compile during installation. This method is used by, for instance, [`leveldown`](https://github.com/level/leveldown) and [`libjpeg`](https://github.com/pkrumins/node-jpeg).
- There are also packages that require libraries to be installed separately, for instance [`qrcodeine`](https://github.com/netoxygen/node-qrcodeine). Installing this package will just fail with a compilation error when one of its prerequisite libraries isn't installed.

A drawback of the last method, aside from just failing with an error, is that it makes versioning difficult. If `MyLib` is being actively developed and changes regularly, you may run into the problem that a Node module that depends on it could be out of date with respect to the (globally installed) version of the library.

Comment: Good point about depending on a separate shared library with regard to versioning. In my case I'm wrapping a library, which provides a public interface with strict backwards compatibility to previous versions. node-pre-gyp looks promising though, thanks for pointing me there.